# Xamarin forms detecting settings changed

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have line of business Xamarin Forms app. For the app to function, the user must have location and notifications on. I am using Xamarin essentials for permission request/check. If the user has already been presented the permission request dialog (and denied it), I throw up the native settings dialog for them to change permissions. How do I tell when my app is back in foreground and verify they changed permission?

Comment: you can use `OnResume` to detect when your app is in the foreground again.  I believe you will just need to prompt the user to re-check permissions

Comment: That actually is not working for me - I assuming just overriding App.OnResume would be the trick too - at least that is what the docs are saying.

Comment: how are you navigating to the native settings dialog?  If you put a breakpoint (or just a Console.Writeline) in OnResume in App.cs is it hit upon return?

Comment: `native settings dialog` - add to question the line(s) of code you use to bring this up. To be sure we are discussing the exact situation you have encountered. Is `OnPreferenceChangeListener` relevant? Though I think that only tells you about individual preference changes, not when the user is finished.

Comment: Set a flag to remember that you are opening preferences. If OnResume doesn't get called, then check that flag in OnAppearing of the page you were on. If that doesn't get called, then are you referring to Settings that can be controlled via androidx.preference library? AFAIK, that won't let you enable location or notifications (once they have been rejected by user) - that has to be done by user in corresponding OS dialogs (to avoid spoofing by malicious apps). In which case, OnResume should definitely get called upon return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making this too difficult. I ended up invoking an event during the App.OnResume that I handled in the ViewModel for the active page (where I initiated the OpenSettingsDialog). From there, I was able to requery the settings for Location and Notification. Thanks all for the comments!